# Number of state variables in the general expression for a state function

Tags: thermodynamics, equation-of-state

In the tenth addition of Physical Chemistry: Thermodynamics, Structure, and Change by Peter Atkins and Julio de Paula, it is given, in section 2E, that the general expression for the differential of internal energy is given by

$$
dU = \left( \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T dV + \left(\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V dT
$$

This would imply that $U = U(V, T)$. However, isn't it true that the *general* expression of a state function depends on, at least, three state variables?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are getting at by "the general expression of a state function depends on, at least, three state variables". Are you effectively asking why there is no pressure dependence for U in the above? Or dependence n the number of molecules in the system? Or something else? It would be good if you gave an example of what you think is a "general expression" and a reference as to why you think that is the case.

Comment: @IanBush it could be either $P$ or $n$, but, afaik, there has to be a third variable.

Comment: Please, a reference to support the assertion that the general expression needs 3 variables. I'm not saying you are wrong, its just i cant remember it being specified as such. And In the case of P in the above the equation of state can always in principle be used to eliminate it from the functional form for U.

Comment: The third state variable is $n$, the amount of matter, in moles

Comment: The definition here is for a pure substance in a closed system.

Comment: At constant n Defining or measuring T and P or V defines the other.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there has to be a 3rd variable, and it is usually mass or particle number. Even for an ideal gas there are 3 *independent* variables in its thermal equation of state $pV=\tfrac{m}{M}RT$.

When you express the internal energy as function of extensive variables, say volume, entropy and mass as $$U=U(S, V, m) = TS-pV+\mu m \tag{1}$$ then $$dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dm \tag{2}$$ and $$T=T(S,V,m)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}, \quad p=(S,V,m)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial p},\quad \mu=\mu(S,V,m)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial m}.$$ Usually, for a closed system, it is assumed that the mass (particle number) is kept constant, $dm=0$, and then you can write $dU=TdS-pdV.$

That ignoring the 3rd variable can lead to nonsensical statements even for a closed is quite evident when you consider the Gibbs-Duhem equation which is a consequence of eq (1) and (2):
$$SdT-Vdp+md\mu =0 \tag{3}$$

If you consider an isothermal process, $dT=0$, you would get $$dT=0 \quad \rightarrow Vdp = md\mu \tag{3a}.$$ But if you ignore the 3rd variable, that is using only $dU=TdS-pdV$ because your system has constant mass, $dm=0$ then it would follow that an isothermal process must also be isobaric, as well, a clearly nonsensical result. The correct relationship, eq (3a), shows that in an isothermal process the mechanical work $Vdp$ is actually done against the system's mass changing its chemical potential, a chemical work. Note that for an ideal gas in which $dT=0$ and $dm=0$, you also have $d(pV)=pdV+Vdp=0$, that is $pdV=-md\mu.$

Comment: OTOH, many parameters that affect U are either constant, either are variables dependent on p,T. So their effect can be implicitly involved in dU/dT resp. dU/dp. All depends on what parameters are explicitly said to be constant. dU/dT without n constant implicitly assumes U=f (T, n)=f(T,g(T)).

Comment: What follows "The correct relationship" is correct but this statement is not: "because your system has constant mass, dm=0 then it would follow that an isothermal process must also be isobaric." The constraints applied to the definition of U apply to the Gibbs-Duhem equation too.

Comment: @BuckThorn the sentence was phrased in the conditional tense with an "if": if one *ignores* the 3rd variable, not that you should, and writes $U=TS-pV$ with $dU=TdS-pdV$ then one gets $SdT-Vdp=0$ which leads to nonsensical result.

Comment: @Poutnik, that is true, and that is why I specifically mentioned the simplest case with which almost all textbooks and courses start, namely, the thermal equation of state $pV=\tfrac{m}{M}RT$ where it is clear that even for an ideal gas there is a 3rd variable and when that is ignored by blindly writing always in the same introductory texts and courses $dU=TdS-pdV$ can lead to nonsensical result.  I am really surprised that anything I wrote above is even controversial.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, you are correct.

Comment: You may want to check punctuation. I still find it a little hard to follow the logical flow in some of the sentences.

Comment: @BuckThorn I suspect that the *true* but never admitted reason for preferring to write $dU=TdS-pdV$ is because a 2-variable differential form is always integrable and this way it is simpler beyond the obvious of having only 2 and not 3 variables. I have never been a teacher of the subject (thermodynamics), I only recall the pain I felt when learning about it but I think this misleading simplification is a terrible historical legacy. Just look the way novices keep getting confused by $dS=\delta Q/T$, what is $Q$ what is $T$, etc., EM diffraction never appears to be so difficult to beginners.

Comment: @hyportnex it's easier to avoid discussion of chemical potential early on, but as you point out this has shortcomings. I'll see if I can think of a way around your argument for why you can't assume U=-pV+TS.

Comment: @BuckThorn I think for regular thermoD system, one that is composed of massive particles, the chemical potential is unavoidable. All massive bodies carry entropy. Even electrons in a metal have an electrochemical potential composed of an electric potential (electric charge) and a chemical potential (inertial mass charge); it is truly an eyeopener for an ElecEeng that a voltmeter measures the electrochemical not the electric potential. I know almost nothing about radiative thermoD, maybe there.